# If $\forall c>0$, $\int_c^\infty|f_n|dx\to0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{-c}|f_n|dx\to0$, then $f_n\to0$ uniformly on $(-\infty,-c]\cup[c,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions on $\mathbb R$ that is an approximate identity. In particular, it satisfies for every real $c>0$,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-c} |f_n(x)|dx\to0\qquad\int_c^\infty |f_n(x)|dx\to0$$

Does it follow that for every $c>0$, $f_n\to0$ uniformly on $(-\infty,-c]\cup[c,+\infty)$?

My intuition tells me that the answer must be positive but I am unable to prove why it is so.

My attempt at proof:

Seeking contradiction, assume that there is $c>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ so that for each $N\in\mathbb N$, there is $n>N$ and $x\in(-\infty,-c]\cup[c,+\infty)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\ge\epsilon$...

I am not sure what to do next. My idea is to show something like $\int_c^\infty |f_n|dx<\epsilon$ and $\int_c^\infty |f_n|dx\ge\epsilon$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Try $c_n = 1+{1 \over n} \sum_k {1 \over k^2}$ and $f_n(x) = {1 \over c_n} \left( 2n \cdot 1_{[-{1 \over n}, {1 \over n}]}(x) + \sum_k 1_{[1-{1 \over n k^2},1]} (x) \right)$.

Comment: Even $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f_n| \to 0$ deos not tell you anything about  a.e. (let alone uniform) convergence of $f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. Here is a counter-example.

Define the function
$$h = \begin{cases} 
  1 - |x| & |x| \leq 1 \\ 
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and let $f_n(x) = nh\left ( n^2(x-1) \right )$.

Geometrically, $f_n$ is a hat function centered around $x=1$ with height $n$ and base $\frac{2}{n^2}$. From this it follows that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f_n| dx = \frac{1}{n}$$
which implies that the sequence $f_n$ satisfies the conditions.

However $f_n$ fails to uniformly converge to 0 on $(-\infty,-c]\cup[c,\infty)$ for any $c < 1$. In fact it doesn't even converge pointwise to 0.

At a high level, uniform convergence and pointwise convergence are much stronger types of convergence than integral-based convergences (like the one you are asking about). It is rarely the case that an integral condition can imply uniform or pointwise convergence without imposing additional conditions.

Comment: Simpler example: $f_n=1_{(n,n+\frac 1 n)}$.